# Hard drive size permanently reduced by docking station

Tags: hard-drive, docking

I obtained a used docking station at a garage sale with no documentation.
When I tried to use it with a 1TB hard drive, it said the drive had only 8 GB capacity.
It changed something on the drive so other computers also think it is only 8 GB.
Before I realized that the docking station was the cause, I tried a second 1TB hard drive, and  the same thing happened to that drive.
**How can I get my hard drives back to full capacity?**

Details:

*Docking station*: I plan on getting rid of the docking station.  It has no documentation and no make or model number visible. It can mount 2 disks in any of 4 modes.  It was set to JBOD.  It has a USB2 interface to the computer and an external power supply.  I suspect it was not designed to handle drives as large as 1TB.

*Hard Drive repair attempts*:  I tried the hard drive on Linux and Windows 10.  "Gparted" on Linux and "Partition Wizard 10" and "AMOEI Partition Assistant" on Win10 all show the size as 8 GB.

*NOTE*: When I say the drive size is 8GB, that is what I mean.  I am not just looking at a partition.  I can make a partition (limited to 8GB) and read and write to it.  But deleting all partitions gives me unallocated space of 8GB.

I suspect I need a very low-level access to the hard drive.  The factory must be able to instruct the drive how big it is (although I am surprised it isn't hard coded in firmware).  Since the docking station changed it, then it must be changeable.  Any ideas?

Comment: The docking station is just a port expander. It shouldn’t be doing any manipulation of the data transferred between the computer and a USB device. It is simply providing a USB port and is not providing the disk access capabilities. This doesn’t really add up.

Comment: Since the dock can do RAID setups, it does have access to the data stream and how/where it is stored/retrieved on the disks.  In JBOD mode, it shouldn't do anything. 
 The fact that it should not have changed anything does not change the fact that two disks were modified.  And the real question is not how it happened, but how to get back full capacity of my disks.  (Where is the full capacity stored, and how can it be modified/corrected.)

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to fix this myself.
A friend uses an Apple computer, and
was able to return the drives to
their full capacity.
(Unfortunately, I do not know the
details of what program/tools he
used to do it.)